# Fields are not getting rendered

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am working on SharePoint online, I have created a simple list with some fields, when i go to new item form and view the page source. I can't find any field in source code, I can see on the user interface but I can't see in page source. Where fields are getting rendered?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Online apply client side rendering (a.k.a `JSLink`) by default to render the form fields. That means rendering the fields via JavaScript code. See more details in [this post](http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/blog/2013/04/14/introduction-to-client-side-rendering-in-sharepoint-2013/).

If you would like to see the HTML source code of the field as it is rendered by `JSLink` I suggest you to start the Developer Tools in Internet Explorer (F12), then from the HTML tab of the tool select Refresh (F5), that is the fourth button on the toolbar, finaly click the first, arrow button on the same toolbar, that is'Select element by click' (Ctrl + B), and select the field in the IE window you would like the source code of. The source code should be displayed in the Dev. Tool now.

The steps I described above is for IE10, the exact steps may depend on the browser version you have.